# Why is '\SO' behaving differently from the other escape codes in Agda?

Tags: escaping, ascii, special-characters, agda

It seems that I can define a character by its escape code, such as

```
mychar : Char
mychar = '\US'
```

But not for '\SO', because

```
mychar : Char
mychar = '\SO'
```

gives

> Lexical error in string or character literal: bad escape code

Even though `Data.Char.show '\14'` gives back `"'\\SO'"`, so I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Is it somehow related to the existence of '\SOH'? What is the best way to print any character in a way that Agda can also read them in?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in Agda's parser, [so I've reported it as such](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/5291). In particular, [the `match` function](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/ecb93230ad9327991e542731756cbe1405c85d5f/src/full/Agda/Syntax/Parser/LookAhead.hs#L106) doesn't work for non-prefix-free cases, such as `SO` vs. `SOH`.  To illustrate, here's a short example:

```
λ» M.parse defaultParseFlags [] (runLookAhead error $ match [("FO", pure 1), ("FOO", pure 2)] (pure 3)) "FOO"
ParseOk (PState {parseSrcFile = Nothing, parsePos = Pn {srcFile = (), posPos = 1, posLine = 1, posCol = 1}, parseLastPos = Pn {srcFile = (), posPos = 1, posLine = 1, posCol = 1}, parseInp = "FOO", parsePrevChar = '\n', parsePrevToken = "", parseLayout = [NoLayout], parseLexState = [], parseFlags = ParseFlags {parseKeepComments = False}}) 2
λ» M.parse defaultParseFlags [] (runLookAhead error $ match [("FO", pure 1), ("FOO", pure 2)] (pure 3)) "FOB"
ParseOk (PState {parseSrcFile = Nothing, parsePos = Pn {srcFile = (), posPos = 1, posLine = 1, posCol = 1}, parseLastPos = Pn {srcFile = (), posPos = 1, posLine = 1, posCol = 1}, parseInp = "FOB", parsePrevChar = '\n', parsePrevToken = "", parseLayout = [NoLayout], parseLexState = [], parseFlags = ParseFlags {parseKeepComments = False}}) 3
λ» M.parse defaultParseFlags [] (runLookAhead error $ match [("FO", pure 1), ("FOO", pure 2)] (pure 3)) "FO"
*** Exception: unexpected end of file
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:31:44 in interactive:Ghci8
```

As we can see, if we have `"FO"` and `"FOO"` as the two cases, parsing `"FOO"` works as expected (returning 2), parsing `"FOB"` works as expected (returning 3 from the default case), but the input `"FO"` leads to a parse error.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent analysis, this shall be fixed in 2.6.2.1.